# How to Hide a Tile from a Sharepoint list based off User Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a Page on a SharePoint site that displays a list, the list is displayed in a tile format, so it looks like the promotional SharePoint link. Is it possible to hide some of the tiles (Rows of the list) based on user permission. For example I want to hide a tile for all non-admins?

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? I clicked edit page and edit web part I see a style script, It doesn't seem to reflect since I tested off by changing one of the colors. Is a list the ideal way for this?

Comment: You can achieve such requirements using quick links web part in SharePoint. Check [this article](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)

Answer (score 0):

First, select a row that you want to hide, and then click on the red marks in the picture below:
[image]

You can click on "stop sharing" (As shown in the picture below) , then other users will not see the row, or you can hide some rows here depending on user permissions:

[image]

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.
If there's anything you'd like to know, feel free to let me know.
Looking forward to your reply.